# Symfony 6 populate Dropdown with Dynamic entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony6

I have a CreditCard entity, on form screen there is a dropdown with user's Bank entities and I want to fill BankAccount dropdown according to selected bank dynamically, I have tried couple solutions from SO and added an event listener to my form but when I change the Bank dropdown I get "Integrity constraint violation: kart_adi (credit card name field on entity) cannot be null. I am using Symfony 6 with php 8.1.2

KrediKarti.php:

```
class KrediKarti
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Banka::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $banka;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: BankaHesap::class, inversedBy: 'krediKartlari')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $hesap;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $kart_adi;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $kart_no;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $hesap_kesim_gunu;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
private $aciklama;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
private $borc;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
private $alacak;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime_immutable')]
private $created_at;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getBanka(): ?Banka
{
    return $this->banka;
}

public function setBanka(?Banka $banka): self
{
    $this->banka = $banka;

    return $this;
}

public function getHesap(): ?BankaHesap
{
    return $this->hesap;
}

public function setHesap(?BankaHesap $hesap): self
{
    $this->hesap = $hesap;

    return $this;
}

public function getKartAdi(): ?string
{
    return $this->kart_adi;
}

public function setKartAdi(string $kart_adi): self
{
    $this->kart_adi = $kart_adi;

    return $this;
}

public function getKartNo(): ?string
{
    return $this->kart_no;
}

public function setKartNo(string $kart_no): self
{
    $this->kart_no = $kart_no;

    return $this;
}

public function getHesapKesimGunu(): ?int
{
    return $this->hesap_kesim_gunu;
}

public function setHesapKesimGunu(int $hesap_kesim_gunu): self
{
    $this->hesap_kesim_gunu = $hesap_kesim_gunu;

    return $this;
}

public function getAciklama(): ?string
{
    return $this->aciklama;
}

public function setAciklama(?string $aciklama): self
{
    $this->aciklama = $aciklama;

    return $this;
}

public function getBorc(): ?float
{
    return $this->borc;
}

public function setBorc(float $borc): self
{
    $this->borc = $borc;

    return $this;
}

public function getAlacak(): ?float
{
    return $this->alacak;
}

public function setAlacak(float $alacak): self
{
    $this->alacak = $alacak;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
{
    return $this->created_at;
}

public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $created_at): self
{
    $this->created_at = $created_at;

    return $this;
}
}
```

KrediKartiType.php:

```
$builder
        ->add('kart_adi',TextType::class,['label' => 'Kart Adı','required' => false, 'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Kart Adı']])
        ->add('kart_no',TextType::class,['label' => 'Kart No','required' => false, 'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Kart No']])
        ->add('hesap_kesim_gunu', NumberType::class, [
            'label' => 'Hesap Kesim Tarihi', 'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Hesap Kesim Günü']
        ])
        ->add('aciklama',TextType::class,['label' => 'Açıklama','required' => false, 'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Açıklama']])
        ->add('borc', NumberType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Borç', 'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => "Borç",'value' => '0.00','style' => 'text-align: right']
            ])
        ->add('alacak', NumberType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Alacak', 'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => "Alacak",'value' => '0.00','style' => 'text-align: right']
            ])
        ->add('banka',  EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Banka::class,
            'choice_label'=> 'adi',
            'placeholder' => 'Lütfen bankanızı seçiniz',
            'attr' =>['class' => 'form-control']
        ))

    ;

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Banka $banka = null) {
        $banka_hesap = null === $banka ? [] : $banka->getBankaHesaplari();

        $form->add('hesap', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => BankaHesap::class,
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices' => $banka_hesap,
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getBanka());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('banka')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $banka = $event->getForm()->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $banka);
        }
    );
```

new.html.twig:

```
<script>
var $banka = $('#kredi_karti_banka');
var $token = $('#kredi_karti__token');
$banka.change(function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    var data = {};
    data[$banka.attr('name')] = $banka.val();
    data[$token.attr('name')] = $token.val();
    $.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    complete: function(html) {
    // Replace current position field ...
    $('#kredi_karti_hesap').replaceWith(
    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
    $(html.responseText).find('#meetup_position')
    );
    // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

I simply want to fetch bank accounts based on the selected bank on bank change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add options to the form when you create it. So you can create an endpoint where you can create the form with the extra options which could be the `bank` id and then render only the select element you wish, in your case the `bank_accounts` select. You can call this endpoint on change event via JS to the `banks` select. Also you need to modify the `KrediKartiType` so that the `bank_accounts` select should take the values from a query builder. For Example:

```
class BankAccountsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/bank-accounts-select', name: 'bank_accounts_select', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function getBankAccountsSelect(Request $request): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(
            KrediKartiType::class,
            null,
            ['bankId' => $request->query->get('bankId')]
        );

        return $this->render('_bank-accounts-select.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The form type for the `bank_accounts` key can look like this:

```
->add('bank_accounts', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => BankaHesap::class,
      'query_builder' => function (BankaHesapRepository $bankaHesapRepository) use ($options) {
           return $bankaHesapRepository->bankAccountsByBankId((int) $options['bankId']);
       },
       'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mb-0 d-block'],
])
```

The Repository method to get the bank accounts from bankId:

```
public function bankAccountsByBankId(?int $bankId): QueryBuilder
{
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('bh')
     ->join('bh.bank', 'b')
     ->where('b.id = :bankId')
     ->setParameter('bankId', $bankId)
     ->orderBy('bh.name', 'ASC') // this is optional :)
   ;
}
```

You would also need the twig file which renders the select element `_bank-accounts-select.html.twig`:

```
{{ form_row(form.bank_accounts, {
    attr: {
        'class': 'mb-3 form-control'
    }
}) }}
```

At last the Js part, where you need to call the endpoint `bank-accounts-select`, where you replace the select with the one you get from the endpoint:

```
$bankSelect.on('change', (event) => {
  const bankId = event.target.value;
  $.ajax({
      url: BASE_URL+'/bank-accounts-select',
      data: {
        bankId: bankId,
      },
      success: function (html) {
        const $bankAccountsSelect = REGION_SELECT_FROM_CLASS_NAME //replace this with your jQuery/Javascript selector;
        $bankAccountsSelect.html($(html).find("option"));
        $bankAccountsSelect.val("").trigger("change");
      },
    });
});
```

**This should do it, And I suggest you use English language on your code ;)**

Comment: Works like a charm, I know the issue about the language, project might need a local development on future so its a little mixed and I regret that. Only issue in here the security, I will relate bank and bank account entities to users so what happens if I replace the bank ID on client. For example you have bank entity with ID of 1 and I have a bank with ID 2, in render I will only fetch the bank with ID 2 for me but what if I change this ID on AJAX to 1 ?

Comment: Then you should change the query to find the banks related to the user that is logged in. You can get the loggedin user from the Formtype directly by injecting the Security component  and update the method to `userbankAccountsByBankId(int $bookId, int $userId)`. With this new param then you can check something like this: `where('bank.user = :userId')->setParameter('userId', $userId)`.

Comment: Thank you I will try that

Comment: Glad I could help